CSS check if round() is available
What's the CSS way to check if the round() function is available in a browser?
The height for this element is zero:
<div class="check_round">
</div>

:root {
--my_height_0: 100.1px;
--my_height: round(up,var(--my_height_0));
}

.check_round {
    background-color: teal;
    width: 100px;
    height: var(--my_height)
}

This version also returns zero:
:root {
    --my_height_0: 100.1px;
    --my_height_1: round(up,var(--my_height_0));
    --my_height: max(var(--my_height_0),var(--my_height_1));
}

I added the rounding interval.
This syntax returns a correct height of 101 in browsers that support round(), but it returns a height of 0 in browsers that do not support round().
:root {
  --my_height_0: 100.1px;
  --my_height: var(--my_height_0);
  --my_height: round(up,var(--my_height_0),1px);
}

This @supports test fails in browsers that support round() and in browsers that do support round():
@supports (round(up,var(--my_height_0),1px)) {
  :root {
    --my_height: round(up,var(--my_height_0),1px);
  }  
}


You should be able to use the supports at-rule https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports

@supports works on declarations not on values.

I don't think this is a use detection issue, it's more "why this implementation doesn't work" thing. I suspect this is a root variable problem, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/round

I tried this @supports syntax.  The test fails and the round() is not applied in browsers that should support round().  won't allow me to include the at supports rules I tried.  I'd appreciate any example of successfully testing and applying the new round() CSS function to a css variable.

you may considerate to consult https://caniuse.com/?search=css%20round() ...before to build your code ?

a perhaps odd question, but: do you actually need rounding? If your calc() are all based on the same vars, then things will get "rounded by the browser" anyway already.

I'd like to use round() because browsers are rendering before and after elements with different heights when the heights are all the same single digit number of pixels plus a fractional pixel.

You are missing the required rounding-interval for round() if the value is not a number as pointed out in the comment. As per spec:

round(<rounding-strategy>?,A, B?): If the type of A matches <number>, then B may be omitted, and defaults to 1; omitting B is otherwise invalid.

As for what rounding-interval do:

Round valueToRound up to the nearest integer multiple of roundingInterval (if the value is negative, it will become "more positive"). This is equivalent to the JavaScript Math.ceil() method.)



console.log(document.querySelector('.check_round').offsetHeight);
:root {
  --my_height_0: 100.1px;
  --my_height: round(up, var(--my_height_0), 50px);
}

.check_round {
  background-color: teal;
  width: 100px;
  height: var(--my_height)
}
<div class="check_round">
</div>




That being said, if you still want to check the support, you can use @supports, though you need to pair it with a property and remove the var() usage withing the test.


console.log(document.querySelector('.check_round').offsetHeight);
:root {
  --my_height_0: 100.1px;
  --my_height: var(--my_height_0);
}

.check_round {
  background-color: teal;
  width: 100px;
  height: var(--my_height);
}

@supports (height: round(up, 100.1px, 1px)) {
   :root {
    --my_height: round(up, var(--my_height_0), 50px);
  }
}
<div class="check_round">
</div>




you may add JS : console.log( document.querySelector('.check_round').offsetHeight );

This is not quite correct. The rounding interval is not always required, only if the value is not a number. Here it's a length so in this case, it is required.

Thanks.  codepen throws this error when testing the at supports rule: Error: Only 1 argument allowed, but 3 were passed.

@Alochi, thanks, I just noticed that and was looking into the spec to find where it is mentioned.

Is there any way around performing the at supports test for the round() function?  I would have expected this syntax to fail if round() is not supported.   Instead it returns 0.  --my_height: round(up,var(--my_height_0),1px);

@fritz Like I provided. Note that you need to remove the var in the @supports test or else it will always be a valid syntax. You can see Why is an unsupported CSS value still overriding its fallback declarations for more detail.

Thanks.  Codepen allows this at support test without throwing an error if round() only includes 1 argument, like so: (height: round(100.1px)).  Round is successfully applied in a browser that supports round().  In a browser that does not support round(), the returned height is 0.

@fritz  You can't do round(100.1px) as mentioned in the answer. Rounding interval is required if the first argument is not a number, such as your case 100.1px . You need to add the second argument or it will be an invalid syntax. This has nothing to do with round() being supported or not.
